# How can I make this gradient compatible with all browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, linear-gradients

I am trying to make this linear gradient browser compatible but I'm not sure how. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FD3D3C 0%, #CC0000 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #CC0000;
```

Comment: There are a few sites out there that can do this - for example [CSS Gradient Background Maker](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
background: #fd3d3c; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fd3d3c 0%, #cc0000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fd3d3c), color-  stop(100%,#cc0000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fd3d3c 0%,#cc0000 100%); /*  Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fd3d3c 0%,#cc0000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fd3d3c 0%,#cc0000 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fd3d3c 0%,#cc0000 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fd3d3c', endColorstr='#cc0000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Use [this site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate gradients.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ :

```
background: #fd3d3c; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZkM2QzYyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNjYzAwMDAiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fd3d3c 0%, #cc0000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fd3d3c), color-stop(100%,#cc0000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fd3d3c 0%,#cc0000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fd3d3c 0%,#cc0000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fd3d3c 0%,#cc0000 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fd3d3c 0%,#cc0000 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fd3d3c', endColorstr='#cc0000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```